# Looking for a causality to effect dataset

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a causality dataset that would look like this:

```
animal + car -> accident
speeding -> traffic ticket
tomatoes + lettuce -> salad
virus -> illness
tooth decay -> dentist
```

Does this already exists?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt anything so general exists. The closest I can think of would be to exploit resources which exist in the medical domain, in particular https://semrep.nlm.nih.gov/

Also try asking on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/